# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `Component` supplied to `PadView`

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `Component` supplied to `PadView`.

Hi, I am new to react-native, the red message just keep showing up, but everything looks fine, and the app rendered out correctly, but the red message just keeps showing up in the terminal, do you guys have any idea what doesn't that mean, thanks for the help.

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `Component` supplied to `PadView`.
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:63:8 in console.error
- node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
- node_modules\prop-types\checkPropTypes.js:20:20 in printWarning
- node_modules\prop-types\checkPropTypes.js:83:12 in checkPropTypes
- node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1796:19 in validatePropTypes
- node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1969:22 in createElementWithValidation
- node_modules\react-native-elements\src\list\ListItem.js:101:4 in ListItem
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10696:27 in renderWithHooks
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13481:6 in mountIndeterminateComponent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20459:25 in beginWork$$1
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19370:24 in performUnitOfWork
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19347:39 in workLoopSync
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18997:22 in renderRoot
* [native code]:null in renderRoot
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18709:28 in runRootCallback
* [native code]:null in runRootCallback
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5642:32 in runWithPriority$argument_1
- node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:643:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5638:22 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5627:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18556:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:21822:15 in scheduleRootUpdate
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:23042:20 in ReactNativeRenderer.render
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\renderApplication.js:52:52 in renderApplication
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:116:10 in runnables.appKey.run
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:197:26 in runApplication
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Comment: Hi, maybe you could post more information like your PadView Code will be more clear to catch the problem.

Comment: Its weird, that is what I don' t understand, because my code doesn't have any "PadView" inside, and I don' t know what is that, I am think it may be inside the module folder.. the weird thing is everything render okay, just those red message show up in the terminal and not goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Update `react-native-elements`. Issue was fixed in version `1.2.2` (was caused by some changes in `propTypes` treatment in React Native 0.61.1 I believe).